# Unable to access rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, openshift, rails-console

I have deployed my application onto openshift and everything is working great until I tried to access the rails console.

```
ssh openshiftsshlogin
cd ~/app-root/repo/
rails c
```

When I run the above command I get this error.

```
bash: rails: command not found
```

My web application is open source which may help to diagnose the error.
[Link to the Github repository](https://github.com/frazboyz/Portfolio-Openshift).

Also when I run...

```
bundle exec rails c
```

I get the following error,

```
bundler: command not found: rails
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:10:in `with_friendly_errors': uninitialized constant Thor::AmbiguousTaskError (NameError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.5.2/bin/bundle:20
from /usr/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
from /usr/bin/bundle:19
```

I dont belive i need to manually install the rails gem as the gear is running a rails application just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So weirdly enough I solved the issue by just running "gem install rails" even though I should not of needed to. So if a future person runs into this issue just run...

```
gem install rails
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails console
```

That should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails console`

Comment: I ran this in /app-root/repo and got this error.

"bundler: command not found: rails
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:10:in `with_friendly_errors': uninitialized constant Thor::AmbiguousTaskError (NameError)
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.5.2/bin/bundle:20
 from /usr/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
 from /usr/bin/bundle:19"

Comment: Why? Why does setting this environment variable work?